# ModelStateValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation

I have this model:

```
        public Flight[] Flights { get; set; }
        public Passenger Passenger { get; set; }
        public ReservationData ReservationData { get; set; }
```

I want to add ModelState Error like so :

```
        Operation.ModelState.AddModelError("Flights", "");
```

But I want to add the error to the items of the flights array separately. so what key do I use?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to add the error to the Flight object specifically?  Is it because you're using a partial view?

Comment: since each of the flights has its own data on the page

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a workaround to me, but still you can make use of `ModelState` in both controller and view directly, and making some kind of flight-specific keys, say by some flight's identifier.

Here is the example which uses flight's index in the array as such an identifier. Controller:

```
...
for (int i=0; i < model.Flights.Length; i++)
{

    //here comes the validation for flight model.Flights[i]
    //if the validation fails, adding error to the model

    Operation.ModelState.AddModelError("Flight" + i, "");
}
...
```

View:

```
<% for (int i=0; i < Model.Flights.Length; i++) { %>

    <%-- flight rendering goes here, including rendering of errors --%>

    <% if (ViewData.ContainsKey("Flight" + i) { %>
        <%: ViewData.ModelState["Flight" + i].Errors[0] %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: what if I want to use  @Html.ValidationMessageFor?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe it won't work. `ValidationMessageFor` gives you error messages associated with specific model properties, and does not support retrieval of error messages by keys. But this is how I understand it, and I might understand wrong, so give it a try!

Comment: However there is one more option - all errors added to the `ModelState` will appear in `@Html.ValidationSummary`.